# Why isn't the PHP file responding to my AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, ajax

I have a HTML file that displays the word "PRESENT".

When I click on the word, I want to send AJAX request to PHP file, which changes the word to "ABSENT" on the screen AND in the database.

There are two problems:

1. The PHP never responds back to the HTML file. If it did, the changeState() function would've fired an alert saying "Server has responded!"
2. The PHP file never executes the SQL statement even when the the changeState() function has been called. If it did, the database would've been updated, which it wasn't.

index.html

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Attendance System</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="1">
      <span onclick="changeState(this)">PRESENT</span>
    </div>

    <script>

    function changeState(elem) {

      var oldValue = elem.innerHTML;
      var newvalue;
      var itemID = elem.parentNode.getAttribute('id');

      if (oldValue == 'PRESENT') {
        newvalue = 'ABSENT';
      } else {
        newvalue = 'PRESENT';
      }

      alert("new value is " + newvalue + ", itemID is " + itemID);

      var xmlhttp;

      if(window.XMLHttprequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
          alert("Server has responded!");
          elem.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }

      xmlhttp.open("GET", "updateState.php?newValue=" + newvalue + "&id=" + itemID, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

updateState.php

```
<?php

// Login procedure code here...

// I tried to substitute this palce with fixed dummy values before and it successfully updated the database. But the code doesn't work when it is like this.
$value = $_GET['newValue'];
$id = $_GET['id'];

// Construct SQL query
$query = "UPDATE attendanceList SET attendOrNot = '$value' WHERE id = '$id'";

// Execute SQL query
mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('Query execution failed! ' . mysqli_error($conn));

// Print result text
print $value

?>
```

Comment: You never set `$value` ?

Comment: @IsThisJavascript, seems like he's doing that.

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to MySQL injection. You should look up [prepared statments](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and give it a try, you'll be protected and stuff like `'` won't break your query.

Comment: @lonut Whoops I didn't notice he set the `$_GET` as `$value`!

Comment: Check your network tab from your console. Make sure the path to `updateState.php` is correct. Also, I don't think `$id` is a string. So it should be `$id` without the ' '

Comment: "The PHP never responds back to the HTML file". Not necessarily. You're only displaying that message when the server responds with a "200 OK" response. If it returns any other response (e.g. 404, 500, etc etc) then your JavaScript code does nothing. Learn how to debug your ajax requests by using the Console and Network tools in your browser's developer tools. You can check that the ajax call actually runs, and you can check both what is _sent_ (in the URL / request body) and what is _received_ (in the Response body, the headers and the status code) during the request. There's no need to guess.

Comment: "The PHP file never executes the SQL statement even when the the changeState() function has been called. If it did, the database would've been updated, which it wasn't." Again, not necessarily. There could be a number of reasons why the script returns "200 ok" but the database table doesn't get updated - even if the SQL gets executed. e.g. 1) $id could be null, 2) maybe $id does not match anything in your database table (note above comment re strings vs ints in the query), 3) maybe the query crashes. Again, debug it properly using the developer tools to see what's actually being sent/received.

Comment: @potatoguy you have add database connection in updateState.php page.

Comment: Hi @ADyson, thanks a lot for the help. I found the error and posted it as an answer below. According to the developer tool, the function never sends out the request to PHP file due to a careless syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in index.html

```
 if(window.XMLHttprequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
```

"XMLHttprequest" should've been spelled "XMLHttpRequest" with a capital R.

Sorry for confusing everyone.